# Raspberry Pi 4 as server with connection to two networks

Tags: database, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I want to use my raspberry as a server.

The Raspberry Pi is connected via Ethernet to the router.
ESP32, a WiFi enabled Microcontroller, is connected via WiFi t the Raspberry.

I want my esp32 to write to the database
and I want in a way that I can read the database through the browser.

Is the approach correct?

Comment: What is esp32 ?

Comment: @Ingo ESP32 is a microcontroller with WiFi connectivity features.

Answer (score 2):

The following answer is assuming you could connect your Raspberry Pi to your router via Ethernet.

You can start a hotspot in your Raspberry Pi and connect your ESP32 via the hotspot.

As per my understanding of the question you've asked, the Database is running in Raspberry Pi. It will be accessible from both the networks. You can therefore get the ESP32 to ingest data to the Database and browse it from any other device connected to your other network.

Useful links:

1. [Creating WiFi Access point in Raspberry Pi](https://www.google.com/amp/s/thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/amp/)

Alternatively, you can connect both your ESP32 and Raspberry Pi to your router's WiFi and achieve the same result. (Assuming your router has WiFi)

Answer (score 0):

I've got one of my Π machines set up as a bridge, following the directions [here](https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/). I can connect to the Π from my network over the Ethernet port, and also, via a separate "non-routable" subnet on the WiFi adapter as a separate network. I believe that's what you're seeking to do.